# Compiling example-mesh.c Contiki

Tags: contiki

How do I fix this error:

```
undefined reference to button sensor
```

when compiling `example-mesh.c` using Micaz mote in contiki?

Here is my code  I run the simulation in the mote output window only 3 messages are sent while the rest is " packet timedout " how can I solve that problem to send messages based on timer value ?

```html
#include "contiki.h"
#include "net/rime.h"
#include "net/rime/mesh.h"

#include "contiki-conf.h"
#include "sys/etimer.h"
#include "sys/process.h"
#include "sys/ctimer.h"


#include "dev/leds.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MESSAGE "Hello"

static struct mesh_conn mesh;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(example_mesh_process, "Mesh example");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&example_mesh_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void
sent(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
  printf("packet sent\n");
}

static void
timedout(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
     
  printf("packet timedout\n");
}

static void
recv(struct mesh_conn *c, const rimeaddr_t *from, uint8_t hops)
{
  printf("Data received from %d.%d: %.*s (%d)\n",
  from->u8[0], from->u8[1],
  packetbuf_datalen(), (char *)packetbuf_dataptr(), packetbuf_datalen());

  packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
  mesh_send(&mesh, from);
}

const static struct mesh_callbacks callbacks = {recv, sent, timedout};
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(example_mesh_process, ev, data)
{

   static struct etimer et;

  PROCESS_EXITHANDLER(mesh_close(&mesh);)

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  mesh_open(&mesh, 132, &callbacks);

 

  while(1) {
   rimeaddr_t addr;
 etimer_set(&et, 5 * CLOCK_SECOND);
 PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
 etimer_reset(&et); 

 
    /* Send a message to node number 1. */
    
    packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
    addr.u8[0] = 1;
    addr.u8[1] = 0;
    mesh_send(&mesh, &addr);
}
  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The two sentences in your question have basically the same content, but as a reader, I still have only a rough idea of what you are trying to do, and what the problem is. You may want to update your question with a little more information, but be sure to read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Not all Contiki applications are buiding for all platforms. Do you really need to use `micaz`? It's ancient.

Comment: yes I need to simulate using Micaz but when compiling gives me a compilation error " underfined button_sensor" how can I overcome that problem @kfx

Comment: Well Micaz motes do not have buttons. Why do you need to simulate an application that requires that button is pressed for a platform with no buttons? You can try to remove references to the button sensor from `example-mesh.c`, then it will compile, but to make it work you need to change the logic in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Micaz mote does not have a button and therefore the reference to the *button_sensor* sensor is not valid.

The example is designed to send a message every time the button is pressed so if you want this example to work you need to rewrite the example to send messages based on a timer value.

Comment: how can I rewrite example to send messages based on timer value ? @Johan Bregell

Comment: Remove the code that links to the button sensor e.g. line #44 and #90.
Then I would look at the _examples/ipv6/simple-udp-rpl/broadcast-example.c_ file to get an understanding on how to do periodic events. 

@AmrMagdy

Comment: could you please write it for me, I wrote it but it does not work @Johan Bregell

Comment: 1. Make a timer:
static struct etimer et;
2. Set the timer (5 sec):
etimer_set(&et, 5 * CLOCK_SECOND);
3. Wait for the timer to trigger an event:
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
4. Reset timer:
etimer_reset(&et);

All except 1. should be in the thread loop!
@AmrMagdy

Comment: After I wrote these lines and I run the simulation in the mote output window only 3 messages are sent while the rest is " packet timedout " how can I solve that problem  @Johan Bregell

Comment: Here is my code I added it in order to overcome problem of only 3 messages are sent while the rest is " packet timedout " @Johan Bregell

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it. However this node is dependent on another node that needs to accept the messages!

```c
#include "contiki.h"
#include "net/rime.h"
#include "net/rime/mesh.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MESSAGE "Hello"

static struct mesh_conn mesh;
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(example_mesh_process, "Mesh example");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&example_mesh_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void
sent(struct mesh_conn *c)
{
  printf("packet sent\n");
}

static void
timedout(struct mesh_conn *c)
{

  printf("packet timedout\n");
}

static void
recv(struct mesh_conn *c, const rimeaddr_t *from, uint8_t hops)
{
  printf("Data received from %d.%d: %.*s (%d)\n",
     from->u8[0], from->u8[1],
     packetbuf_datalen(), (char *)packetbuf_dataptr(), packetbuf_datalen());

  packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
  mesh_send(&mesh, from);
}

const static struct mesh_callbacks callbacks = {recv, sent, timedout};
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(example_mesh_process, ev, data)
{
  static struct etimer et;

  PROCESS_EXITHANDLER(mesh_close(&mesh);)
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  mesh_open(&mesh, 132, &callbacks);

  while(1) {
   linkaddr_t addr;
   etimer_set(&et, 5 * CLOCK_SECOND);
   PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

    /* Send a message to node number 1. */

    packetbuf_copyfrom(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
    addr.u8[0] = 1;
    addr.u8[1] = 0;
    mesh_send(&mesh, &addr);
  }
  PROCESS_END();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: it is still not working yet after using that code the mote output window gives me "packet timedout" @Johan Bregell

Comment: So you are clearly waiting for god to solve this for you!  However to help you I need to know your node setup and network config!

Comment: how to get node setup and network configuration @Johan Bregell

Comment: you might want to start there, I would recommend that you first try out your config in cooja so you can get the output from the nodes and see the traffic and then when that works put the code on physical nodes in the real world!

Comment: I am trying the code with cooja but I am telling you my main problem which I could not fix it even after I wrote the code you have written it to me is once I start simulation mote output window in cooja gives me "packet timedout "  no  packets are sent between nodes I tried to fix it many times but it dosen't work @Johan Bregell

Comment: Your problem is somewhere between cooja and contiki, the cooja end is this.  `[java]  WARN [Thread-22] (Radio802154PacketConverter.java:189) - No cross-level conversion available: negative packet length`  This however only appears when running on micaz motes so more investigations are needed!

Comment: what investigations should I do and where should it be done ?? @Johan Bregell

Comment: Well if something is not working and you get an error you usually wanna find why that error is produced. In this case the example-mesh works on for example sky motes so I would look at the difference between sky and micaz and se if is a settings problem. If not then something else on a lower level might be wrong and then you will have to look into the micaz simulation files!

Comment: I could not find the error or the difference could you please write it for me @Johan Bregell

Comment: No that I will not do! However you could put an issue on contikis git repository and see if somebody know anything over there.